# Struggling with installation RxJS ( VS code )

Tags: javascript, html, rxjs

I've created **index.html**, attached to it **script.js** and installed RxJS with `npm install rxjs`. But there are a lot of issues with that[image]

This is what console writes when I comment out my imports statements

[image]

And this is when I use import in **script.js**

Updated: I have linked 
`<script  src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>` 
to the html, but it didn't work out

[Check for the files on GitHub](https://github.com/mxnvkv/rxjs-issue)

Comment: try to uncomment import in your script.js

Comment: @ОлегВойтинський , as you see, I wrote what my console sends me when I uncomment my import. Or it works properly on your side?

Comment: It doesn't. Try to add to your srcipt:<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>

Comment: Still throws an errors, but different

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/guide/installation#all-module-types-cjs-es6-amd-typescript-via-npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out.
this should be your html (make sure that your cdn math is the right path)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script  src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is your js code:

```
const { of, fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { map, pluck, mapTo } = rxjs.operators;

const keyup = fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
const keycode = keyup.pipe(
 map( event => event.code )
);

const keycodePluck = keyup.pipe(
 pluck('code')
);

const pressed = keyup.pipe(
 mapTo('Key pressed!')
);

pressed.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: You didn't. It's because of ES6 features (modules are a part of ES6). And you must use Babel for enabling those features. You didn't neither me). I found a description here https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs for common JS (as i understand without es6)

Comment: Is it possible to install it only with npm? I tried it, but no way it was done successfully